# CodeIgniter returns "Undefined property: Rubrica::$usuario_model" trying to load function model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

I am working with CodeIgniter. In my "instancia" controller I need to create an instance from the controller "rubrica" to access a function from this.

instancia.php:

```
include_once APPPATH.'controllers/controller_ppal.php';
include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/rubrica.php');

class Instancia extends Controller_Ppal
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->no_logged_msg = 'Debe estar autenticado en el sistema para acceder a esta opción.';
        $this->no_auth_msg = 'No tiene autorización para acceder aquí.';
        $this->no_partic = 'No ha agregado participantes a la lista aún.';
        $this->datos_inc = 'No ha ingresado todos los datos de al menos uno de los participantes.';

        $this->load->model('instancia_model');
        $this->load->model('usuario_model');
    }

    ...

    function guardar()
    {
        $ext_class = new Rubrica();
        $ext_class->session = $this->session;
        $ext_class->load->model('usuario_model'); //In spite of it is loaded in "__construct" function
        $id_rubrica = $ext_class->guardar();
    }
}
```

rubrica.php:

```
include_once APPPATH.'controllers/controller_ppal.php';

class Rubrica extends Controller_Ppal {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->no_logged_msg = 'Debe estar autenticado en el sistema para acceder a esta opción.';
        $this->no_auth_msg = 'No tiene autorización para acceder aquí.';
        $this->load->model('rubrica_model');
        $this->load->model('tag_model');
        $this->load->model('usuario_model');
    }

    function guardar()
    {
        $_POST['usuarios'] = $this->usuario_model->todos_usuarios($this->session->userdata('id_usuario'));
    }
}
```

I get the error message "Undefined property: Rubrica::$usuario_model". I have read several posts and I can't get the solution. Could someone help me?

Comment: Codigniter does not allow this as its not good MVC practice. what you can do is add shared function to a parent class in your Core directory., then extend your controllers from it.

Comment: check this out: **[How to create two parent controllers in Codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913036/how-to-create-two-parent-controllers-in-codeigniter/28349963#28349963)**

Comment: and for libraries: **[Codeigniter: Extend Custom library from core folder in a libary class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507742/codeigniter-extend-custom-library-from-core-folder-in-a-libary-class/28507805#28507805)**

Comment: But it is the only model that I can't access. The "tag_model" and "rubrica_model" are loaded successfully

Comment: model? it seems like you are trying to access other controllers from within a controller..

Comment: I access to "rubrica" controller but when I try to use the "todos_usuarios" function from the "usuario_model" model, I get this error: Undefined property: Rubrica::$usuario_model. Both (function and model) works normally in other calls.

Comment: So from what I understand you are in `Instancia` controller, and you are accessing another controller called `Rubrica` from `Instancia`, where you then try to run a model `todos_usuarios` through it? ... Why not access the model `todos_usuarios` directly from `Instance` ??

Comment: Yes, it is: "So from what I understand you are in Instancia controller, and you are accessing another controller called Rubrica from Instancia". From "rubrica->guardar()" function I have many operations depending from parameters, it doesn't only call the model

Comment: You will run into issues when you're application grows. This is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have functions which needs to be shared between multiple controllers, you should write a library.

In application/libraries create Tools.php (or whatever you want)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tools
{
  protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function myfunction($data)
    {
       //If you want to use codeigniter's functionalities :
       //use $this->ci->function()
    }

}
```

And then in your controllers :

```
$this->load->library("tools");
$this->tools->myfunction($data);
```

If your library is meant to be used very often, you can load it once for all in config/autoload.php :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'tools', '...');
```

Comment: And why only this model is not working? It can't be loaded from the new instance from "rubrica" controller.

Comment: How can I load the "usuario_model" model within this library?

Comment: First load it : `$this->ci->load->("usuario_model")` Then call your model function : `$this->ci->usuario_model->myfunction($data);`